# Why does Android "kills" backgrounds apps? What can you do about it?

Tags: android

I'm only on search for the reason why Android does this and what can you do to "stop" it or handle it when coding any app. I haven't found any info about this except some yt videos that teach you how to stop it when using your Android smartphone. I'm looking for documentation or something like that to read and learn why does this happen and how to handle it.

Sorry for my bad english, not native. Thank you.

Comment: If this is about a background service being killed, the only real option you have is making it a foreground service.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads?hl=en#Processes https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/process-lifecycle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why? Because a device is a computer and therefore the limited resources should be optimized. The optimizations favors the app with the user is interacting, making the user experience fluid.

How this happen and how to handle it is the [life cycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle)

And how to make things even if the app is not open it is about the [workmanager](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/basics)

Answer (score 1):

From the official **[documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/process-lifecycle)**

> It is important that application developers understand how different application components (in particular Activity, Service, and BroadcastReceiver) impact the lifetime of the application's process. **Not using these components correctly can result in the system killing the application's process while it is doing important work**.

and how it happens :

> To determine which processes should be killed when low on memory, Android places each process into an "importance hierarchy" based on the components running in them and the state of those components